# Delete a Character from Every Word in a String Except One Certain

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, indexing, replace

So I need to remove for example the letter "a" from every word in a string which is an element of array, except the word "an"

```js
var arr = ['sentence example', 'an element of array', 'smth else']
var removedPuncts = []
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (sentences.indexOf("an")) {
    ...
  }
}
console.log(removedPuncts)
//expected output: ['sentence exmple', 'an element of rry', 'smth else']
```

So maximum I thought it'll be needed to find an's index, but don't have an idea what to do next.

Comment: "*…except the word “an”" - what about - for example - the words “ran,” “lane,” “ant,” “pant”…?

Comment: @DavidThomas Of course ran, lane, ant, pant and all other word including letters "an" in them are different words and a must be deleted in them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression - match `a` with negative lookahead for `n`.

```js
const arr = ['sentence example', 'an element of array', 'smth else'];
const output = arr.map(str => str.replace(/a(?!n)/g, ''));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: What if I need to remove the question marks, but not from the word `word?`. there can be such an example as `word?s`, and here it's not the same thing, so question mark must be deleted.

Comment: Add a word boundary after matching `?`? `\?\b`

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['sentence example', 'an element of array', 'smth else'];
let out = []
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let text = ""
    for (j = 0; j < arr[i].split(" ").length; j++) {
        if (arr[i].split(" ")[j] == "an") {
            text += "an"
        } else {
            text += " " + arr[i].split(" ")[j].replaceAll('a', '')
        }
    }
    out.push(text)
}
console.log(out)
```